# Apple Music can't obtain library

Tags: itunes, wifi

I have been experiencing the following:

- Leave the house in the morning with MacBookPro turned on from day before
- slightly/not use it until I got back home and then use it

**Problem:** My Apple Music library is greyed out when coming back home and only the downloaded songs will play (even though I have a stable connection). 
At home I am connected to WiFi (which works), during the way to work not, at work again (obviously a different WiFi than at home).

To resolve the issue I always had to to quit and restart iTunes. Then it loaded the library within a second. I have also restarted the Mac.
I have not yet done:

- SMC reset
- unlink Apple Music account and relink
- deleted WiFi settings and reconnect

**Question:** Do you know of this issue and how to resolve it? And do my own suggestions make sense?

Comment: Restarting iTunes doesn‘t help?

Comment: Yes, it does help. I will clarify